# Connection to Encrypted ElastiCache Redis from Java using a CName

Tags: java, ssl, redis, amazon-route53, amazon-elasticache

I am using the Lettuce driver from spring data to connect to an ElastiCache using in transit encryption. When I try to connect to the Route53 CName assigned to the ElastiCache cluster. I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='my.cname.net', port=6379]]
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:507)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:481)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectClusterAsyncImpl(RedisClusterClient.java:335)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.RedisClusterClient.connectClusterAsync(RedisClusterClient.java:273)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceClusterConnection.doGetAsyncDedicatedConnection(LettuceClusterConnection.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.getAsyncDedicatedConnection(LettuceConnection.java:3466)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.getDedicatedConnection(LettuceConnection.java:3487)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnection.java:3460)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.sMembers(LettuceConnection.java:1998)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Here is the code I am using to connect:

```
@Bean
public static RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> source = Maps.newHashMap();
    source.put("spring.redis.cluster.nodes", "my.cname.net:6379");
    RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(new MapPropertySource("RedisClusterConfiguration", source));
    clusterConfiguration.setMaxRedirects(10);
    LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfiguration);
    factory.setValidateConnection(false);
    factory.setUseSsl(true);
    return factory;
}
```

Now when I replace the Cname with the acual network name attached to the ElastiCache cluster the program works. Does anyone know why the Program is failing only when using the Cname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a very similar problem with a .NET client. I believe the problem is because the certificate that the Redis end point is for the amazonaws.com domain so connecting to the cluster via your CName of my.cname.net fails because the certificate is not valid for that domain. We were unable to find any way of changing the certificate so could not work around the issue and had to stick with using the actual network name in the connection.